# Mac OSX 10.8.4 - Apache - Setting up Virtual hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, virtualhost

I can't seem to get my virtual hosts working:

I have an /etc/apache2/users/scottr.conf set up as:

```
<Directory "/Users/scottr/Sites/">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I then have my /etc/apache2/extra/ set up as:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Users/scottr/Sites/"
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName whatever
    DocumentRoot "/Users/scottr/Sites/work/whatever/"
 </VirtualHost>

http://localhost works fine, but I can't get http://whatever/ to work at all.
```

Seems pretty basic.

What am I missing?

```
/var/log/apache2/error_log doesn't show any entries if I go to http://whatever/
```

/etc/apache2/httpd.conf is default:

```
# User home directories
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

# Real-time info on requests and configuration
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-info.conf

# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

# Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-manual.conf

# Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-dav.conf

# Various default settings
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-default.conf
```

/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf :

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf
```

-- Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an entry for `whatever` in /etc/hosts?

e.g.

```
127.0.0.1  whatever
```

Comment: Doh!  Yes, that's it.  So, what does an app, like MAMP do for these?  Is that app writing to the host file as well?

Comment: I'm not familiar with MAMP, but a quick look at the docs doesn't say anything about having to manually add local DNS entries, so I'd guess yes!